# Will this JavaScript timezone function translate best to a Java double primitive?

Tags: java, javascript, timezone

I need to pass the JavaScript `tz_offset` variable on the client size to a Java `tzOffset` on the server side. `tz_offset` is calculated here:

```
time: function(){
  var d1 = new Date(), d2 = new Date();
  d1.setMonth(0); d1.setDate(1); d2.setMonth(6); d2.setDate(1);
  return({tz_offset: -(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()) / 60, observes_dst: (d1.getTimezoneOffset() !== d2.getTimezoneOffset()) });
}
```

What is the best Java primitive data type to represent the offset? A String, double or int?

**My best guess is a `double` but I'm worried about outliers that may not be representable as a `double`.** For now I'm leaving it as a String since that seems safer - but not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, most dates are stored as Long values. As they represent the time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds, you don't need floating point precision (a la Double), but you need more bits than an Integer will give you.

So, I would choose Long, unless you are worried about non-numeric values coming from your javascript code, and instead want to use a String and perform the conversion to a numeric on the serverside.